# Send output from iPython console to .csv file. (& viewing data issue)

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Using the iPython console, I built a pandas dataframe called df.

```
for (k1,k2), group in df.groupby(['II','time']):
    print k1,k2
    print group
```

df['II'] stores integers between: [-10,10].

'time' can be either 930 or 1620

My goal is to save the output (of this loop) to a single .csv file. (Not great, but I copied and pasted the output to a csv. However, in doing so, I noticed that "II"==  -1, at both times: 930/1620, do not appear in (full data view) like the others. (They both exist, though).

For example, for "II"==  -1 @ 930 it appears in the console as :

```
-1 930
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 268 entries, 2 to 2140
Data columns:
index      268  non-null values
date       268  non-null values
time       268  non-null values
price      268  non-null values
round5     268  non-null values
II         268  non-null values
Pattern    268  non-null values
pl         268  non-null values
dtypes: float64(2), int64(4), object(2)
```

With the knowledge that it exists, I tried brute force, pulling them manually:

```
u=df['II']== -1
one=df.groupby('time')[u]

#To check the result: 

one.to_csv('file.csv')
```

I'm grouping by 'time', so all times should appear. Yet the resulting csv only contains the 1620 times--all results at 930 are, unfortunately, missing in action. It's bizarre. Your suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to share code that generates a DataFrame that has this issue?

Comment: I think, when you call `to_csv` on the groupby object, it calls `to_csv` on each group in turn. So it saves the 930 group, then overwrites it with the 1620 group. Try it without the `groupby('time')`.